# CSS Grid using float items

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

I am trying to implement a simple grid with 3 square items per row and each item can have up to 3 rows/cols. Here's what I have so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/dt3u6840/

HTML:

```
<div class="layout-grid">
 <a href="#" class="block" data-rows="2" data-cols="2"></a>
 <a href="#" class="block" data-rows="1" data-cols="1"></a>
 <a href="#" class="block" data-rows="1" data-cols="1"></a>
 <a href="#" class="block" data-rows="1" data-cols="1"></a>
 <a href="#" class="block" data-rows="1" data-cols="1"></a>
 <a href="#" class="block" data-rows="1" data-cols="1"></a>
 <a href="#" class="block" data-rows="1" data-cols="3"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.layout-grid { overflow: hidden; max-width: 800px; width: 100%; }
.layout-grid .block { position: relative; display: block; float: left; background-color: green; height: auto; transition: all .3s ease; }
.layout-grid .block:hover { opacity: .2; }
.layout-grid .block:nth-child(odd) { background-color: blue; }
.layout-grid .block[data-cols="1"] { width: 33.33333333333%; }
.layout-grid .block[data-cols="2"] { width: 66.66666666666%; }
.layout-grid .block[data-cols="3"] { width: 100%; }
.layout-grid .block[data-rows="1"] { padding-top: 33.33333333333%; }
.layout-grid .block[data-rows="2"] { padding-top: 66.66666666666%; }
.layout-grid .block[data-rows="3"] { padding-top: 100%; }
```

This works great. However, if I try to add an item with > 1 rows it doesn't:

https://jsfiddle.net/pz4vhjw6/

NEW HTML:

```
<div class="layout-grid">
 <a href="#" class="block" data-rows="2" data-cols="2"></a>
 <a href="#" class="block" data-rows="1" data-cols="1"></a>
 <a href="#" class="block" data-rows="1" data-cols="1"></a>
 <a href="#" class="block" data-rows="1" data-cols="1"></a>
 <a href="#" class="block" data-rows="1" data-cols="1"></a>
 <a href="#" class="block" data-rows="2" data-cols="1"></a>
 <a href="#" class="block" data-rows="1" data-cols="1"></a>
 <a href="#" class="block" data-rows="1" data-cols="1"></a>
</div>
```

Is there anything I can do to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [*`CSS Grid layout`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) here - not that its supported in modern browsers only (see [support info](https://caniuse.com/#search=css-grid)). Here you can use a 3 column layout and *span* the rows and / or columns to get the desired layouts - see a demo below with both of your layouts:

```css
.layout-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; /* 3 columns */
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.layout-grid .block {
  background-color: green;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  padding-top: 100%; /* set height of block */
}

.layout-grid .block:hover {
  opacity: .2;
}

.layout-grid .block:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.layout-grid .block[data-cols="2"] {
  grid-column: span 2; /* occupy 2 columns */
  grid-row: span 2; /* occupy 2 rows */
}

.layout-grid .block[data-cols="3"] {
  grid-column: span 3; /* occupy 3 columns */
  grid-row: span 3; /* occupy 3 rows */
}

.layout-grid .block[data-rows="2"] {
  grid-row: span 2; /* occupy 2 rows */
}

.layout-grid .block[data-rows="3"] {
  grid-row: span 3; /* occupy 3 rows */
}
```

```html
<div class="layout-grid">
  <a href="#" class="block" data-rows="2" data-cols="2"></a>
  <a href="#" class="block" data-rows="1" data-cols="1"></a>
  <a href="#" class="block" data-rows="1" data-cols="1"></a>
  <a href="#" class="block" data-rows="1" data-cols="1"></a>
  <a href="#" class="block" data-rows="1" data-cols="1"></a>
  <a href="#" class="block" data-rows="1" data-cols="1"></a>
  <a href="#" class="block" data-rows="1" data-cols="3"></a>
</div>

<br/>

<div class="layout-grid">
  <a href="#" class="block" data-rows="2" data-cols="2"></a>
  <a href="#" class="block" data-rows="1" data-cols="1"></a>
  <a href="#" class="block" data-rows="1" data-cols="1"></a>
  <a href="#" class="block" data-rows="1" data-cols="1"></a>
  <a href="#" class="block" data-rows="1" data-cols="1"></a>
  <a href="#" class="block" data-rows="2" data-cols="1"></a>
  <a href="#" class="block" data-rows="1" data-cols="1"></a>
  <a href="#" class="block" data-rows="1" data-cols="1"></a>
</div>
```